# How to call a activity from a handler class

Tags: java, android

**What does my App need to do :**
the app should start with fingerprint authentication then MainActivity should start.my fingerprint authentication contains a handler class where it validates the fingerprint
after validating fingerprint I need to start MainActivity.

i've tryed to use Intent inside handler class but it says me error

Is There Any Way to Call MainActivity from Handler Class ?

Anyone Please Help Me to Solve this problem

**Handler Class**

https://github.com/MrRockerZ/code-share/blob/6fc58239dc80ed462737f7785637c41f8deffa7f/Handler%20Class

**Android Manifest**

https://github.com/MrRockerZ/code-share/blob/6fc58239dc80ed462737f7785637c41f8deffa7f/AndroidManifest

Comment: From where you are calling Handler?

Comment: i am calling it from FingerActivity

Comment: then create a callback and send it from your Hander and receive it inside FingerActivity.

Comment: which concept i need to use for callback.can you please explain me for it.

Comment: create an interface.